How "trim" spell check's language list (aspell)
I use evince as PDF viewer and I noticed an annoying issue: spell check language list is filled with useless english variants;
(see screenshot below)

Question is: How to trim down the list to a couple of entries?
I am Italian but I also write in English so I need both language but, thus I have installed both aspell-en,aspell-it packages;
Even if all those English variants have probably a good reason to exists, I do not need and I want to hide them, since make the workflow more complicated and a waste of time.

EDIT:

this question is evince or better aspell-specific, since the former's spell checker is based on it;
I am looking for any kind of solution: a "proper" one if it exists, or a brutal one as @tink point out, that's simply delete implicated files


Arch Linux w/ Evince-46.3.1 aspell-0.60.8.1 aspell-en-2020.12.07

Different distro, but does this set you on the right path?

@tink yes and no; I updated OP; unfortunately hunspell-solution doesn't fit since aspell provides much more kind of files en{.dat,.multi,rws,alias}; that's, which one I have to delete?
